# What is the rarity for the various loot spawns in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

There are multiple loot rarities in Fortnite: Common, Uncommon, Rare, Epic and Legendary.

What is the percentage rarity for loot of each level to spawn in Fortnite?

Comment: Do you want the rarity per weapon so uncommon till legendary for pistol , shotgun etc or just the basic chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is [a website](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/weapons) that displays all the drop chances per weapon. per rarity. They also display the chance per loot source of getting this weapon. As it is quiet a long list I shall display it for one weapon for example sake.

[This link](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/loot), provides you with a list of dropchance per "loot container" (chest, floor, supply drop)

Note: this data is subject to change per patch. As the game is constantly updated. Therefor do not take the example data listed below as correct.

Example weapon M4:

- [common](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/weapons/assault-rifle-m4-common) : Floor loot (so laying in the open), 25.9% chance. Chest 12.9%
- [uncommon](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/weapons/assault-rifle-m4-uncommon) : Floor loot (so laying in the open), 12.9% chance. Chest 6.5%
- [rare](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/weapons/assault-rifle-m4-rare) : Floor loot (so laying in the open), 5.2% chance. Chest 2.6%